# Pycharm building wheel: "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pycrypto

**Situation:**
I had this error

`File "D:\Documents\Python_projects\stable_env\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 23, in <module>`
`from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'`

**Solution:** I tried `pip3 install pyrebase`

**Problem:** `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome`

```
  Moving to d:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\lib\site-packages\crypto\
   from d:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\lib\site-packages\~rypto
  Moving to d:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\lib\site-packages\pycryptodome-3.10.4.dist-info\
   from d:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\lib\site-packages\~ycryptodome-3.10.4.dist-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
aymer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yxkp7g76\\pycryptodome_a53664fc52004d7f8956259824cec980\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aymer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yxkp7g76
\\pycryptodome_a53664fc52004d7f8956259824cec980\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools impo
rt setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-record-na3bmx_0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\documents\python_projects\stable_env\include\site\python3.7\pycryptodome' Check
 the logs for full command output.
```

If I try to `pip3 install pycrypto`, I have the same error.

BUT, they propose me `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

When I try to install it, it takes too much space for my `C:`.
I'm not sure what I can try now to debug this.

Comment: OK, I found out how to solve this precise problematic. I found out a pyrebase and a pycryptodome version on my settings that I uninstalled. But that doesn't answer the global problematic of the wheels.